# How to install ESP32 support into Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

Here the link to the page that tells me how to give Arduino the capability to create sketches for my ESP board:

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/windows.md

> open a Git Bash session pointing to `ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK_DIR` and execute `git submodule update --init --recursive`

I have identified the `ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK_DIR` from the Arduino IDE. So I do have a path that points from the `C:\` drive to this directory. What fails is when I do open GIT Bash and change current directory to the one I have defined as being the `ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK_DIR` and do enter the command as shown GIT bash complains "No such file or directory". Effectively this directory is still empty.

Just for completeness of my question. I have followed the instruction on the page whose link I gave to this point where I do no know how to get ahead!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change slashes form "\" to "/" and "C:\" to "c/", and put it in double quotes. Like:

> cd "/c/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32"